# Any pointers on cleaner way to maintain state accross view in backbone.js application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two dropdowns in a view along with some links.  If I change values in a dropdown, data gets refreshed in the view. I need to maintain the changed state of the dropdowns to the next view.

1. Any recommended way of doing this?
2. Is maintaining state really the way applications are written in backbone?

Comment: Define across views? Just use the same model for both views.

Comment: @Raynos maintaining state of some user selected option from view1 to view2

Comment: is a view a server side view? is it a backbone view? is it a page? etc

Comment: Then share the model. The data is still there in the page. It's all in javascript on one page. It's already persistant.

Comment: Related: http://xkcd.com/138/

Comment: How does one get from one view to another?, Like, are they clicking a link, which takes them to a different page, or are they clicking a link which shows something else via js?

Answer (score 1):

As is being advised in the comments, backbone.js would have you manage your data in models outside of the view.  You still have data in the DOM, but you serialize it into data managed by a model.

In your particular case, it sounds like you may have one underlying model which is used by two views.  Your first view probably needs to register a function for a DOM event triggered when the drop down changes.  This function then updates the underlying model.  If you other view is on the page and if it has registered to listen for the model's 'change' events then it can refresh itself.  Whether it does or not, the underlying model should have the same data.

I think the best advice to give you is to re-read the backbone.js documentation and carefully go through any examples that they give or that you can find otherwise.